# Entity Framework Core and multithreading

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core application, I have some complex business logic involving multiple threads doing database operations outside the scope of an HTTP request. Accessing the database from the same thread processing the request is trivial, but when spawning threads that requires their own DbContext, this turns out to be tedious. As the DbContext itself is not thread-safe, I have tried to create a new DbContext together with its options in addition to obtaining a DbContext from an IServiceProvider. With both approaches, I get the following exception:

> An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A
>   DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is
>   still being configured at this point.

I'm getting the impression that I'm approaching this problem the wrong way and that I'm not supposed to handle database connections like this. How am I then supposed to obtain a DbContext in a separate thread from the one processing incoming requests?

Comment: Create a new instance of DbContext in every thread you use. DbContext is not thread-safe.

Comment: Can you provide a piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested and it works:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
                            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(DbConnectionString);

                            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
                            {

                                //save or update() on *context* here
                            }
```

Answer (score -1):

It turned out my test code had a small typo making it use the same DbContext across all threads. It is however required that I create a new DbContext instance but I cannot obtain one through the IServiceProvider as mentioned in my question.